# asterisk macro-auto-blkvm set variable

Tags: asterisk, context, freepbx

Добрый день!

Необходимо в macro-auto-blkvm определить переменную, которая далее будет доступна в последующих контекстах и макросах.

Пробую так:

```
[macro-auto-blkvm]

include => macro-auto-blkvm-custom

exten => s,1,Set(__MACRO_RESULT=)

exten => s,n,Noop(===>>>> ANSWER RING <<<<===)

exten => s,n,Set(__MYNEWVAR=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%F %T)})
```

но не вижу `${MYNEWVAR}` в других контекстах и в макросах, например в `macro-hangupcall`. Если делать через `GLOBAL` то проходит, но по логике так нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перемення теряется т.к. далее уже другой канал. Чтобы передать переменную в другой канал необходимо использовать SHARED():

1. Записали переменную с нужным каналом:

   exten => .,n,Set(CURCHANNEL=${CHANNEL})
2. Далее создаем нужную нам переменную и делаем шаред в ранее определенный канал

   exten => s,n,Set(SHARED(MANAGERANSWDATE,${CUR_CHANNEL})=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%F %T)})
3. Считываем ее в нужном месте:

   ${SHARED(MANAGERANSWDATE,${CUR_CHANNEL})}